# Как правильно запихнуть canvas в поток?

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

Есть код, который закрашивает голубыми квадратами изображение. Происходит это все сразу при открытии приложения. Как сделать, чтобы постепенно на глазах закрашивались эти квадраты с какой-то задержкой? То есть нужно видимо цикл занести в поток

MainActivity

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private View drawView, drawViewRect;
    int i, j;
    String Tag = "oh!";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        setContentView(drawView);

        for (i = 1; i <= 36; i++) {
            for (j = 48; j >= 1; j--) {
                drawViewRect = new DrawViewRect(this);
                setContentView(drawViewRect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DrawView

```java
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint p;
    Rect rect;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    String Tag = "Oh!";

    private int startX = 0;
    private int startY = 0;

    private int endX = 0;
    private int endY = 0;

    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) {{
        setDither(true);
        setColor(Color.RED);
        setStrokeWidth(20);
    }};

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        p = new Paint();
        //шаблон квадрата
        rect = new Rect(0, 940, 20, 960);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //фоновая заливка
        canvas.drawARGB(80, 102, 204, 255);

        //фоновая картинка
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, p);
    }
}
```

DrawViewRect

```java
public class DrawViewRect extends View {
    Paint p;
    Rect rect;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    String Tag = "Oh!";

    //конструктор
    public DrawViewRect(Context context) {
        super(context);
        p = new Paint();
        //шаблон квадрата
        rect = new Rect(0, 940, 20, 960);
    }

    public DrawViewRect(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        p.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 255);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, p);
        canvas.translate(0, -20);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. В классе **DrawView** из метода **onDraw** убираем циклы с квадратиками; т.о. метод будет вызываться 1 раз и отрисовывать только фон и картинку.
2. Создаем еще один класс **DrawViewRect** для отрисовки квадратиков; в нем метод **onDraw** будет вызываться столько раз, сколько у нас квадратиков. Сюда помещаем содержимое из циков с квадратиками.
3. В том месте, откуда у нас вызывался изначально первый клас с методом **onDraw**, вызываем его, а затем строим циклы, а внутри циклов вызываем второй класс с методом **onDraw**. Перед вызовом добавляем строчку **Thread.currentThread().sleep(200);**

Comment: Пробовал, изображение появляется лишь после того, как полностью все закрасится. До этого момента (пока идет цикл) экран пуст

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, посмотреть так или нет. Исправил вопрос. Этот код не работает, рисует только один квадрат (и фона нет).

Comment: Ведь в DrawViewRect нет значений координат?

Comment: Простите, но я не понимаю. Как добавить? Еще одни циклы?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `postInvalidateDelayed()`.

Вот простой пример, как можно рисовать линию постепенно.

```
public class DrawView extends View {

    private int startX = 0;
    private int startY = 0;

    private int endX = 0;
    private int endY = 0;

    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) {
        {
            setDither(true);
            setColor(Color.RED);
            setStrokeWidth(20);
        }
    };

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, paint);

        if (endX != 300 && endY != 300) {
            endY++;
            endX++;

            postInvalidateDelayed(1000 / 30);
        }
    }

}
```

И не делайте 
`bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic);`
в onDraw(). Лучше вынести инициализацию в конструктор.